# ng-click not working in IE on option select angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown

I'm using following HTML code 
**HTML:**

```
<select style="width: 100%" name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model="data.multipleSelect" multiple>
    <option ng-click="BRPTab.AddFilesToOpenorDelete(fileName)" ng-repeat="fileName in BRPTab.FileNames">{{fileName}}</option>
</select>
```

Here BRPTab is an Alias.

**Script code:**

```
scope.AddFilesToOpenorDelete = function (FileName) {
        scope.SelectedFiles = [];
        var request = { FileName: FileName };
        scope.SelectedFiles.push(request);
}
```

This is working fine in Chrome but not in IE. Please suggest.

Comment: may I know which IE version & angular version? And `BRPTab` stands for what?

Comment: Can you please any plnkr/fiddle?

Comment: @ELmissaouihabib IE version 11

Comment: @PankajParkar IE 11, angular version 1.4.7, BRPTab stands for controller alias.

Comment: I changed it to :  
<select style="width: 100%" name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model="data.multipleSelect" ng-change="BRPTab.AddFilesToOpenorDelete(data.multipleSelect[0])" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="fileName in BRPTab.FileNames">{{fileName}}</option>
</select>

and it worked.

Comment: Maybe it's just that IE 11 respects strict mode, which means if you do something like: (function () {
    "use strict";   ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-click on `options` tag would not work. Do use `ng-options` directive then, that would make you code more cleaner.

```
<select style="width: 100%" name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" 
  ng-model="data.multipleSelect" multiple 
  ng-options="fileName in BRPTab.FileNames"
  ng-change="BRPTab.AddFilesToOpenorDelete(data.multipleSelect)">
</select>
```